# Convert nvarchar scientific notation value into number in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column loaded into SQL Server with these `nvarchar` values:

```
ColumnName
==========
6.19e+014
.....    
6.19e+014
```

Now, what would be the easiest way to convert this value into numbers again.

Kindly suggest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @String varchar(25)='6.19e+014'

Select cast(@String as float)
```

Returns 619000000000000

Answer (score 0):

This will cast to `FLOAT` without issue:

```
SELECT CAST('6.19e+014' AS FLOAT)
```

If what you really want is the specific value that got converted to scientific notation in the first place, you'll have to go back in the process to before it got converted and fix that.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to fix the issue before the conversion. While importing the data from excel, this mess-up happened. Can you suggest how I can fix the issue?

Comment: It's a result of the formatting type used in Excel, it's inferring the datatype. I know there are a number of solutions, easy is saving your excel file as csv, or changing fields to text, but that might not be sustainable if it's a frequent task.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try this

```
Select convert(numeric(15,0),ltrim(rtrim(str(column_name,15))))
from table_name
```